# how to execute inline javascript inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, inline

is it possible to execute inline javascript inside an iframe?
The **script tag** is there, but nothing is executed, for example not even the **alert**.

Am i missing something?

The page is not mine, but the software allows me to enter **HTML tags**.
The software is a teaching platform, which allows me to enter different elements like PDFs, HTML, images, text, and it displays them in the page inside an iframe.

Is there a security reason maybe, that explains why the **script tag** is not executed inside the iframe?

Thanks

Here i have an example of the page

[image: example]

Comment: "_the software allows me to enter HTML tags_" Which software? I suppose "_the software_" doesn't execute the script you've entered when adding it to the DOM.

Comment: the software is a teaching platform, which allows me to enter different elements like PDFs, HTML, images, text, and it displays them in the page inside an iframe.

Comment: this is the platform https://www.anewspring.com/

Comment: i removed everything except the alert. It doesn't work also.

Comment: It looks like the script is added to the DOM. If you'll exit the edit mode, and navigated to the page as a normal visitor, is the script then executed? If not, you should see a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) error in the console.